# Является ли серьезной ошибкой хранить пол как строку?

Tags: java, ооп

У меня в классе Person должен храниться пол. Сейчас я храню строкой `"муж"` и `"жен"`. Нужно ли делать перечисление?

В целом, я понимаю что перечисление лучше. Если бы у меня было текстовое поле для ввода пола то это позволило бы избежать ошибки. Например если бы пользователь вводил `"муж"` по русски, а раскладка клавиатуры включено английская, то в базу попало бы `"ve;"` . Но у меня на форме 2 `JRadioButton`. Так что пол точно будет либо `"муж"` либо `"жен"`. В данной ситуации наверное без разницы как хранить, перечислением или строкой, правильно?

Comment: Можно `boolean isMale`

Comment: @Suvitruf а почему не isFemale???

Comment: @PashaPash я сексист )

Comment: @Suvitruf, не удачный пример привел. А если бы надо было хранить время суток. И соответственно было бы 4 JRadioButton. Как лучше было бы хранить, строкой или перечислением?

Comment: @PashaPash, можно таки добавить метод `isFemale()` коий будет возвращать `!isMale()` =)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб... а `isMale()` будет возвращать `!isFemale()` :)

Comment: @PashaPash, Haskell-way

Comment: на последнем проекте видел абсолютно трешовую базу данных. при попытке сделать с нее миграцию постоянно все падало. после немногочисленных усилий было установлено, что причиной было то, что в строчном поле "пол" старой базы данных было указано "самка дельфина". дальше решайте сами...

Answer (score 15):

Java-код любит семантику и value-типы. Всегда лучше иметь `enum`, чем строковые литералы, раскиданные по коду.

Сегодня у вас просто `"муж"` и `"жен"`, приходящие из `JRadioButton`.  Завтра вы захотите добавить в двух классах проверку значения и впишете туда `if (value == "муж")`. Послезавтра к `"муж"` и `"жен"` потребуется добавить `"не определился"`. Потом добавятся проверки в еще трех классах. А еще через некоторое время вам по какой-то причине нужно будет заменить `"муж"` на `"мужской"`, а  `"жен"` на `"женский"`. Или сопоставить каждому полу дополнительные метаданные. Тут-то вы и порадуетесь, что у вас есть один enum из которого вы можете управлять допустимым множеством значений типа "Пол".

Comment: Всегда, если это не Android )

Comment: @Suvitruf, а у Android с этим проблемы? Java ME, например, не любит много разных классов из-за маленького PermGen.

Comment: Я точно знаю, что в первых версиях Android (до 2.1) не использовались почти `enum`'ы в sdk, чтобы увеличить перфоманс. Вместо этого были строковые константы.

Comment: Кстати, джавовый enum мне нравится как раз тем, что это полноценный класс и в нем можно хранить хоть данные, хоть методы даже.

Answer (score 15):

Пожалуй, это зависит от того, чей пол вы храните и кто заказчик.

- Если это база данных крупного рогатого скота или персонажей mmorpg, то полов всегда будет ровно два и они всегда будут определены. Тогда можно выбрать между `isMale` и `isFemale`
- Если это база данных пользователей соцсети для лесбиянок, геев, бисексуалов и трансгендеров, то двух полов вам точно не хватит. Делайте перечисление сразу, т.к. потом рефакторить и заменять boolean на enum будет сложно.

Все остальные варианты лежат где-то между этими двумя крайностями. В любом случае принимайте решение, опираясь на прогноз вероятных будущих изменений. В большинстве случаев вам понадобится более чем два значения пола.

Answer (score 2):

В последние годы задача становится все более актуальной. Теперь почти всегда на форме регистрации или настройке профиля имеется не две радио-кнопки для пола, а три:

- муж
- жен
- неопр

или даже намного больше ([tumblr genders](https://ageofshitlords.com/list-of-all-tumblr-genders-so-far)). Поэтому программы должны адаптироваться. Если как минимум 3 пола можно указать, то `boolean` переменная не подойдет. Перечисление - уже лучше. Но обычно если есть перечисление, то во всех местах приложения, где нужно как-то обрабатывать пол, или выводить его на экран, будет присутствовать это перечисление. Соответственно, для того, чтобы добавить новый пол в уже существующее перечисление, нужно будет во всех местах использования перечисления сделать правки - что довольно затруднительно, но можно. Все-таки перечисление полов достаточно редко меняющаяся вещь! :)

Есть и еще один подход. Создать интерфейс `interface Gender`, описать в нем необходимые для работы с полами методы (например методы `String name()`, `List<Gender> fitTogether()`), и насоздавать реализаций этих методов: `class Male implements Gender`, `class Female implements Gender`. В таком случае, надо будет позаботиться о том, что интерфейса `Gender` хватит для задач вашего проекта при работе с полами, и, как бонус, можно будет не думать о содержимом перечисления полов, так как всегда идет работа с абстрактным интерфейсом.